# On libgdx catching onClose window event

Tags: java, events, libgdx

I am working on a libgdx game and I'd like to use the preferences for storing player's advances and preferences.

So far so good. In android there are nice events for updating the preferences and storing them into the file system.

I was wondering if something similar does exist on the desktop side. Namely, is there any way of adding a listener for whe user is closing the window?

That way I'll be able to flush data before application closes.

Or there are any other method?

Comment: What if the application crashes? Why don't you just flush after every change?

Comment: First of all i would suggest to `flush()` preferences on change and player advance, depending on gamedesign, maybe if he reaches a special "safepoint", or if he presses "safe" button in the menu.
For the question how to flush it on closing the window: Shouldn't `dispose()` be called on window close? There you can simply `flush()` changes.

Comment: @Springrbua, Ahh you r absolutelly right. I just forgot that my main game class is implementing ApplicationListener. Which got dispose.

Comment: I add it as an answer then xD

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your main game implements `ApplicationListener`, which has the `dispose()` method. This method gets called, if you close your window or exit the game. So you can simply `flush()` your `Preferences` in the `dispose()` method.
But as @noone said you should also think, that your app could crash for some reason. If this happens `dispose()` won't be called. It won't be that big problem for `Preference`s like Soundoptions or Graphic settings, as you can easily set them next time, but if a Player looses his progress, he will be frustrated. So i would think about using one of the following methods:

1. `flush()` on every change. You can be sure everything is safed. For progress you can `flush()` on some special events/safepoints
2. `flush()` after some time. Lets say every 5 minutes?
3. `flush()` on a KeyEvent/Button press in the menu.